# Ubuntu 12.04 flash player graphical glitches when minimized

Tags: linux, firefox, flash, nvidia-graphics-card, transparency

I have a bit of an issue where when I am playing a flash video in a minimized window the video will bleed through completely black pixels, especially in conjunction with transparency.  My flash is 11,2,202,236, hardware acceleration is enabled, and I'm running nvidia proprietary drivers (version 295.40-0ubuntu1).

Here's a screenshot of the effect: [image: Minimized youtube video bleeding through]

Before you make fun of me for being a derp for taking a picture of a computer screen, this effect does not appear on standard X screenshots.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue outside of disabling hardware acceleration of flash videos?  My Google well is coming up dry on this one.

Further testing shows that this is only affecting both Firefox and Chromium.  My Firefox version is 14.0.1.  Chromium version is 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It seems related to this bug on launchpad.  But there's no fix listed.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/764620

Comment: There is a stack exchange site specifically for Unbuntu:- http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @rgvcorley doesn't mean Ubuntu questions are offtopic on [su]

Comment: Didn't say it was did I? Was just pointing it out - you're more likely to find someone that knows the answer to your question on a site dedicated to the subject. Nazi moderators!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a workaround change the RGB value of your black screen from #000000 to #000001.